# Is it possible to define our own asp controls in bound field like Template field?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question may be a repetition.but i haven't got a good answer for the question : difference between bound field and template field?.I have a asp gridview.I had found that bound field is used to bind the data directly by using header text and datafield with out using any controls.

template field

```
 public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control Container)
    {
   //code
    }
```

bound field

```
protected override void InitializeDataCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlRowState rowState)
    {
    //code
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TemplateField is more flexible than boundfield.

Both of them will add one column to your gridview, however templateField will allow you to customize this column.

By example, you can add validation controls in an edit Template to validate TextBox control. You can add even complex tables into your column.

You dont have this flexibility in boundColumn

**Summary :**

If it is only for displaying data we should be using boundfield.

If the requirement is also include editing the data we should use Template field.

[TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx)

> Represents a field that displays custom content in a data-bound
>   control.

[BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx)

> Represents a field that is displayed as text in a data-bound control.

Comment: I saw InstantiateIn to add more controls to template field.The same thing can be done in InitializeDataCell of bound field.Then what is the difference?

Comment: In initializedatacell, its not a control but a field